# Convert Json information into a F# list

Tags: json, list, f#

I am discovering Json files and I would like to create a F# code that would read the following Json file (extracted from Facebook connect) and put the datas in F# lists like in this case: `["id";"Name";"first_name";"last_name";"link";"username";"birthday";"gender"]`. Do you have any ideas ? I am not an expert in this and it would be very helpful for me if you have an idea about this

The Json file :

```
{
  "id": "6234306", 
  "name": "Katter Maxime", 
  "first_name": "Katter", 
  "last_name": "Maxime", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/katter.maxime", 
  "username": "katter.maxime", 
  "birthday": "11/10/1982", 
  "work": [
    {
      "employer": {
        "id": "10164958321", 
        "name": "Bedur"
      }, 
      "position": {
        "id": "14014810602", 
        "name": "student"
      }, 
      "start_date": "0000-00", 
      "end_date": "0000-00"
    }
  ], 
  "education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "107990348", 
        "name": "AAAAAAAA"
      }, 
      "year": {
        "id": "1406175699", 
        "name": "2007"
      }, 
      "type": "Graduate School"
    }
  ], 
  "gender": "male", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "updated_time": "2011-11-03T17:31:04+0000", 
  "type": "user"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**jsonKeys.fsx:**

```
#r "System.Web.Extensions.dll"

open System
open System.IO
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Web.Script.Serialization

let _ =
  let jsonStr = File.ReadAllText "json.txt"
  let jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  let dic = jss.DeserializeObject(jsonStr) :?> Dictionary<string, obj>
  let keyList = dic.Keys |> Seq.toList
  printfn "%A" keyList
```

**DEMO**

```
>fsi jsonKeys.fsx
["id"; "name"; "first_name"; "last_name"; "link"; "username"; "birthday"; "work";
 "education"; "gender"; "locale"; "updated_time"; "type"]
```

**ADD CASE OF INPUT LIKE**

```
{"data":[{"id":"902395","name":"Thomas Girba"},{"id":"194589","name":"Durand Gure"},..]}


let listToTuple [x;y] = (string x, string y)
let _ =
  let jsonStr = File.ReadAllText "json2.txt"
  let jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  let dic = jss.DeserializeObject(jsonStr) :?> Dictionary<string, obj>
  let data = dic.["data"] :?> obj []
(*
  let result =
    data
    |> Array.map (fun x -> (x :?> Dictionary<string,obj>).Keys |> Seq.toList |> listToTuple)
  printfn "%A" result //[|("id", "name"); ("id", "name")|]
*)
  let result =
    data
    |> Array.map (fun x ->
         let d = x :?> Dictionary<string,obj>
         string d.["id"], string d.["name"] //value
       )
  printfn "%A" result //[|("902395", "Thomas Girba"); ("194589", "Durand Gure")|]

open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
let arrayToTuple (ar: 'a array)  =
  let len = Array.length ar
  let ty = FSharpType.MakeTupleType(Array.create len typeof<'a>)
  FSharpValue.MakeTuple(ar, ty)
```

Comment: Ok thank you but how do you get the answer please ? the best thing would be a tuple ("id";"6234306");("name";"Katter Maxime")

Comment: PS : what i meant by "how do you get the answer" is not to have the result "id" but the id of the person, here "6234306"). As I asked prevously, the best thing would be a tuple, do you think it's possible ?

Comment: @katter74 , if you want KeyValuePair List then "dic |> Seq.toList". if you want tuple List then "dic |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Key, x.Value) |> Seq.toList" .

Comment: It works really well in this case. Do you know what to do when i have the following file (list of friends provided by facebook):  {"data":[{"id":"902395","name":"Thomas Girba"},{"id":"194589","name":"Durand Gure"}, ... i would like to create a list of tuples with ("id","name");("id","name");("id","name")...

Comment: you need key ("id","name"), really?

Comment: i need to register for each friend his "id" and his "name"

Answer (score 4):

Using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
[ for KeyValue(key, _) in (JObject.Parse(json) :> IDictionary<_,_>) -> key ]
```

Comment: I have the following error : error FS0001: Type not compatible. waiting for
    JToken -> 'a    
but obtaining
    KeyValuePair<'b,'c> -> 'b * 'c    
The type 'JToken' does not correspond to the type 'KeyValuePair<'a,'b>'

Comment: One more comment : do you have any idea of how to have a tuple as a result ? something like ("id";"6234306");("name";"Katter Maxime") ...

Comment: I forgot the cast to `IDictionary<_,_>`. It's fixed. You'll have to use recursion to output key/value pairs correctly, but to get top-level children you can do: `JObject.Parse(json).Children<JProperty>() |> Seq.map (fun p -> p.Name, p.Value.ToString())`.